# fame on realm of the mad god

Tags: realm-of-the-mad-god

How do you get fame on Realm of the Mad God? I got it somehow but I don't know how I did. Can someone shed light on this for me?

Answer (score 0):

You earn fame whenever you die.

[Realmeye](https://www.realmeye.com/wiki/fame-earning):

> When your character dies, you earn fame after the great deeds your character has achieved. Fame can be used to buy certain items in-game, and also a requirement for completing Class Quests. ... There is a certain “base fame” your character receives, and the different achievements add a percentile bonus to this base value. Your total earned fame will be the sum of both.

The bonuses mentioned are linked here: https://www.realmeye.com/wiki/fame-bonuses.

[Wikia](http://realmofthemadgod.wikia.com/wiki/Fame):

> Fame can be gathered from defeating monsters. The harder the monsters you fight, the faster you gain fame. ... At first, you won't be able to keep track of how much fame you earn. After you reach level 20 (the maximum level), you will see an orange bar replace the green one that shows your experience. This bar shows how much fame you have when you mouse over it, and will fill as gain fame for the particular character you're playing as.

Before you die, you have to collect it by defeating monsters or accomplishing other great deeds.